# Change title for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE activity

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I plan to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent to allow user select folder to store some files. But by default sidebar menu title is "Open from".
Is it possible to change it to custom?